# Create Conversion for derived IDbCommand class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqlclient

I've created a derived IDbCommand classe that I want to use for easier Sql-DB Access.

```
internal class Prozedur : IDbCommand
{
    private SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    private SqlConnection connection;
    string commandtext;
    CommandType commandType;
    ...
```

Now I want to expand this class to handle the value assignment from the output parameters of the sql-procedure to the properties of a local class like this:

```
Prozedur p = new Prozedur();
object.Name = p.Parameters["@Name"].Value;
```

This obviously won't work as there is no conversion for this. I know that using

```
object.Name = (string)p.Parameters["@Name"].Value;
```

will work. How do I have to expand the Prozedur class, so I will be able to use

```
object.Name = p.Parameters["@Name"].Value;
```

and do other stuff like checking the parameter values or check for null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a method to access those values and return them already typed:

```
public TValue GetValue<TValue>(string parameterName)
{
    // Do stuff here before returning the parameter value...
    return (TValue)Parameters[$"@{parameterName}"]?.Value;
}
```

Later, you'll access your parameters' values as follows:

```
string name = proc.GetValue<string>("name");
```

Other than that... there's another approach on which you would implement a method to get values of specific types:

```
public object GetValue(string parameterName)
{
    // Do common stuff here to any parameter value type
    return Parameters[$"@{parameterName}"]?.Value;
}

public string GetString(string parameterName)
{
     // Do common stuff here to string parameters only
     return (string)GetValue(parameterName);
}
```

Comment: Of course, sometimes you just get stuck and completely forget the obvious...;) Thanks!

Comment: @Mister832 No problem, sometimes we need to hear the obvious too :D